# Accessing value by key in Directory<system.String, system.Object> - C# Unity Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

This piece of code listens to any changes in my Firebase and fires HandleListChange() when it detects a change:

```
void SetRoomListListener()
{
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
        .GetReference ("Rooms")
        .ValueChanged += HandleListChange;
}
```

My `HandleListChange()` looks like this at the moment:

```
void HandleListChange(object sender, ValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.DatabaseError != null) {
        Debug.LogError (args.DatabaseError.Message);
        return;
    }

    // We got the new data
    foreach (DataSnapshot room in args.Snapshot.Children) 
    {
        string roomName = room.Key;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Object> info in room.Value) 
        {
            Debug.Log (info);
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging `room.Key` gives me name of the room as I want it and `room.Value` returns some kind of dictionary -> `Dictionary2[System.String, System.Object]`. I want to access a value in that Dictionary using a key let's say `room.Value["size"]` but I get this error from the foreach-loop `foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type object because it does not contain a definition for GetEnumerator or is inaccessible`. I've tried quite a few other methods but can't get this to work. This is my first time working with both: directories and firebase, so I have no clue whats going on. Firebase API for Unity is quite minor and internet is not helping much either. I guess this problem is more likely on the C# side, not on Unity's or Firebase's. How can I access my values using a key in that directory? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1a45e32265ebf6ad5ee66848b425e9a934) it seems that `DataSnapshot.Value` returns an `object`, which may encapsulate different native types.

If you are sure `room.Value` contains a dictionary, then you should just cast it and then access its members like any dictionary in C#:

```
var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)room.Value;
var exampleValue = dictionary["size"];
```